# Go a page instead of opening a new tab

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf, in a spring boot program

When an user click this link i want to goto a page

```
<td><a th:href="@{/editings/testament/} + ${testament.id}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a></td>
```

In my controller I have

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER') ")
@GetMapping(value = "/editings/testament/{testamentId}")
public String editTestament(Model model, @PathVariable Long testamentId) throws Exception {
    ....
    model.addAttribute("testamentId", testament.getId());
    model.addAttribute("testamentDocument", testament.getTestamentDocument());
    ...
    return "starter";
}
```

Actually when User click the link that open another tab with the starter page...

How to avoid that

Comment: Is your page with 'editings' named 'starter' ? Inside return statment you need to pass your template name. You can also redirect to another controller method by `return "redirect:/path/from/controller/${testament.getId()}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason that the page is opening in a new tab is because of the target="_blank" attribute present on the a tag.

If you remove this, you should be all set. The controller shouldn't need to be edited to make this happen. Here is a resource to read more: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Hope you're having a good day!

Comment: I was just specifying that we shouldn't have to change the controller - Updated for clarity :D